# How to set up "No Input Prompts" for whatsapp bot which is developed on Google Dialogflow CX and deployed through Twilio

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, dialogflow-cx

I have a bot which is developed on google dialogflow cx and is deployed on whatsapp through twilio. Is there any way to setup no-input prompts directly from the interface or do i need to create some sort of handler to address this. If so then how?

I have tried setting up No input and No matches through dialogflow cx itself but apparently that only works for voice calls.